# in unit test, set mocked value to an argument (pass-by-reference)

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

I have a method:

```
-(void)startTaskForResult:(long long*)result {
  ...
}
```

The function I want to unit test invoke above function:

```
-(void)doWork {
 long long result = 0;
 [self startTaskForResult:&result];
}
```

I am using [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/reference/#argument-constraints) library to do unit tests. In my test case, I want to set the `result` argument to an mocked value e.g. 100 without care about the actual implementation of `-(void)startTaskForResult:(long long*)result`.

I tried the following way:

```
-(void)testDoWork{
// try to set 100 to argument 'result'
OCMStub([classToTest startTaskForResult:[OCMArg setToValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((long long){100})]]);
// run the function, but it doesn't use mocked value 100 for argument 'result'
[classToTest doWork];
...
}
```

But, when I run my test, it does't use the mocked value 100 for argument `result`. What is the right way to set mocked value to argument in my case then?

Comment: From the code you've posted it's not clear where `classToTest` comes from. If it isn't a mock you can stub methods on it.

Comment: `classToTest` is not a mock, it is an initialized instance e.g. `[[MyClass alloc] init]`

Comment: Just to confirm: you can only stub methods on mocks. The object in an `OCMStub()` call must be a mock. Otherwise nothing will happen. This is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Few points to answer your question:

Code for your problem:

```
- (void)testDoWork 
{
    id mock = OCMPartialMock(classToTest)
    OCMStub([mock startTaskForResult:[OCMArg setToValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((long long){100})]]).andForwardToRealObject;
    // set your expectation here
    [classToTest doWork];
}
```

1. To solve your particular problem:

   - Your object should be partial mock
   - Your method should be stubbed (you did it)
   - Your stub should be forwarded to real object (i assume you need method `startTaskForResult:` implementation to be called)
2. However, you face the problems because you are using wrong approach to test;

There're 3 most common strategies to write unit tests:

1. Arrange-Act-Assert used to test **methods**
2. Given-When-Then used to test **functions**
3. Setup-Record-Verify used to test side effects. This usually requires mocking.

So:

- If you want to test that `startTaskForResult:` returns particular value - you should call just that and expect return value (not your case, method return type is void)
- If method changes the state of object - you should expect that state change, like property value or so
- If calling of `doWork` has a side effect of calling `startTaskForResult:`, you should stub it and expect it's call, almost like i've written in code above. However **(!!!)**, however you shouldn't expect things like this. This is not a kind of behaviour that has much sense to test, because it's internal class implementation details. One possible case, when both methods are public and it's explicitly stated in class contract, that one method should call another with some preliminary setup. In this case you expect method call with some state / arguments.

To have your application code testable, you require continuously refactoring your code. Some code is untestable, it's probably better to adopt application code rather then try to cover it with tests anyway. You lose the initial goal of tests - refactoring safety and low cost of making changes.